# Android Studio- Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabn

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

error

```
Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabn
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabn, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

build.grape(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 27

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'here`
```

build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
}}

allprojects{
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

How to fix this problem?